# optimization 2000 + customize shape use ExtrudeGeometry to 3D in secne

Tags: three.js

I maked a lot of customize Geometry in three.js , the cpu use rate very high and FPS low.
a customize Geometry have a different color
How can i get a way to optimization this problem,thanks.

[link description here](http://map.ckiosk.cn/map/txdl/)

Comment: We'll need more information than that. Please review [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without seeing any of your code, we'd be guessing, at best.

Comment: [link](http://map.ckiosk.cn/map/txdl/) example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extensive use of text might be your problem.
[Here](https://www.eventbrite.com/engineering/its-2015-and-drawing-text-is-still-hard-webgl-threejs/) is an article with more explanations and some nice solutions.